# How to augment d3-selection module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

I have a project using TypeScript and d3. I have installed 'd3', '@types/d3' and use d3 like this:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
const x = d3.scaleLinear ...
```

It worked fine until I want to use `d3.scaleSymlog` which is not declared in current '@types/d3-selection'.

I tried to augment 'd3-selection' module:

```js
declare module 'd3-selection' {
  export function scaleSymlog(...);
}
```

But after doing that, all symbols from 'd3-selection' and even other d3 submodules used in my code now can't be found:

```
Property 'mouse' does not exist on type 'typeof import("<project>/frontend/node_modules/@types/d3/index")'.
```

And TypeScript documentation says:

```
You can’t declare new top-level declarations in the augmentation – just patches to existing declarations.
```

So, how can I properly declare and use `scaleSymlog`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `d3-selection` exports this method?

Working with the code you provided appears to augment the `@types` package correctly. Possibly check your TypeScript version or `tsconfig` settings?

Additionally, are you sure the types are *wrong*? Testing this gives a runtime error because `scaleSymlog` is not a function.

```js
import { scaleSymlog, select } from "d3-selection";

declare module "d3-selection" {
  export function scaleSymlog(something: number);
}

// scaleSymlog(1) <-- Runtime error
// select("something") <-- Still valid
```

[image: Edit d3-selection-types]